# What happened to my ASP.NET website causing NullReferenceException in code behind on controls from MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, nullreferenceexception, pageload, app-offline.htm

I have the strangest problem! I have an ASP.NET website application (luckily not yet live). Yesterday and everyday before, I could run the application without error. It was working fine when I turned the computer off late last night. When I ran the application today, I got a strange message telling me that my website was offline and that I should remove the `app_offline.htm` page from my root directory to put it back online.

I have never seen this message or page before, so I searched online to find that apparently SQL Server can put it there temporarily while it's busy to stop any more incoming requests (or something similar). Its proper use is to stop requests going to your site when you are updrading or doing maintenance. I proceeded to remove it as suggested. I cleaned and built the solution and then tried to run it. It no longer runs.

Now, I get an error in my `MasterPage` code behind where I normally access the controls on the `MasterPage` in the `Page_Load` event handler (shown below).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    breadCrumb.BreadCrumbs = BreadCrumbs;
    header.MenuItems = MenuItems;
    footer.Footers = Footers;
    head.Controls.Add(CreateCssLink("~/Stylesheets/main.css", "screen"));
    head.Controls.Add(CreateJavaScriptLink("~/Scripts/site.js"));
    if (Context.Session != null && Session["layout"] == null) Session["layout"] = "single";
    if (!ArePreferencesVisible) preferences.Visible = false;
}
```

I want to be clear here... there are no errors in this code. There are correctly named elements in the `MasterPage` that correspond to those in this code. It has always worked as expected up until today and I have not changed any code since it was last working. I now get a `NullReferenceException` on the first line because the `breadCrumb` element is `null`. In fact, all the elements from the page that are referenced here are `null`.

Normally the page elements have been initialised by the time the `Page_Load` event is raised. What can have caused this to stop happening?

I have double checked that the MasterPage and its code behind file are still connected and they are. I also tried moving this code to the `Page_LoadComplete` event handler, but the controls had still not been initialised, even at that stage. I shouldn't really have to change the code because it worked just fine before.

I also commented out this code and the website ran, albeit without any styles. Interestingly, when I returned the original code to the event handler and refreshed the page, it actually worked again just as it used to. I loaded a number of different pages successfully and I thought it had fixed itself, so I restarted the application and then got the same error again. No amount of cleaning, building, changing solution configuration or restarting the application and Visual Studio make any difference.

I'm not sure if the `app_offline.htm` is a red herring, but I've never seen that before either so it might be connected somehow. From what I read, it seems that just removing it causes the server to restart the application domain automatically, so I can't see the connection.

I really hope someone has come across this bizarre situation before because I'm all out of ideas and I can't run my website until this is fixed.

Comment: I do not think, nether can find how sql server can set the app_offline.htm on the site.

Comment: I typed `app_offline.htm` into google and the 3rd result is this page: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/215912/why-app_offline.htm-is-created-automatically-whats-the-mystery. It appears that you didn't look too hard. Either way, I was not claiming that SQL Server did that, just that I had read that.

Comment: say that the visual studio 2008 add this file, yes this is correct, visual studio when is load the project add this file, and when the project if fully loaded is delete it. If for any reason fail to delete it the file remains. The visual studio when you develop the site. The SQL did not know where to place it... anyway I will check this again but I do not think sql do that in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally tracked down the problem. I had an earlier backup of the website from a few days ago, so I loaded that up and it worked, albeit missing the last few days' work. I copied the latest project code into the Visual Studio > Projects folder leaving the old code in the Visual Studio > Website folder. I loaded the solution and it ran fine again.

I basically compared the Website files, updating each one in turn and periodically running the application. Eventually, the application stopped working. The last file that I had updated was a `MasterPage` file that extended the `MasterPage` that had the problem.

What I had done was comment out an empty `Page_Load` event handler in the `MasterPage`. I don't understand why that would cause this problem, so any comments explaining that would be helpful and appreciated.

This `MasterPage` is only used on the home page and a few others, so that explains why I didn't come across the problem the night that I changed it. (I hadn't viewed any pages that used that `MasterPage` after making the change). I wish I had because it would have been much easier to track down then, but such is life.

So I replaced all of my latest code, added the empty `Page_Load` event handler in the `MasterPage` again and finally, everything is working again.